# MongoDB Connection Error (SASL) with Docker - Windows 10

Tags: mongodb, docker

I'm working on a mobile app project with 2 folders for :

- the front-end (8080 as a local port)
- the back-end, written in Go

Every folder is suited for containers in Docker.

I gathered the both parts in a same folder for an easier management.

The back end is divided into 5 containers :

- mongo
- redis
- redis_commander (8082)
- mongo_express (8081)
- backend (5000)

This last backend container (5000) causes the following SASL error :

```
/app/db/db.go:53 +0xbf

2021/07/22 10:15:15 Database:mongo:27017

panic: server returned error on SASL authentication step: BSON field 'saslContinue.mechanism' is an unknown field.
```

Meanwhile, I also :

- deleted the containers, the volumes and the images
- builded every part again several times
- reviews my config files, also with my colleagues who founded the system

Now, I wonder if I mispelled or missed a parameter in my config files :

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.6'
services:
  backend:
    build:
      context: ./src
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - "5000:8080" 
    expose:
      - 5000
    networks:
      - backend-network
    depends_on:
      - mongo
      - redis
    env_file:
      - backend_config.env

  mongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: on-failure
    volumes:
      - db-volume:/data/db
      - dbconfig-volume:/data/configdb
    networks:
      - backend-network
    env_file:
      - db_config.env

  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    networks:
      - backend-network
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    env_file:
      - db_config.env

  redis:
    image: redis:6.0.3-buster
    restart: on-failure
    networks:
      - backend-network

  redis-commander:
    image: rediscommander/redis-commander:latest
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
    - 8082:8082
    networks:
      - backend-network
    depends_on:
      - redis
    environment:
      - REDIS_HOST=redis
      - PORT=8082


volumes:
  db-volume:
  dbconfig-volume:

networks:
  backend-network:
```

**backend_config.env**

```
MONGODB_USERNAME=root
MONGODB_PASSWORD=example

DATABASE=mongo:27017
DATABASE_NAME=admin

ACCESS_SECRET=abc
REFRESH_SECRET=xyz
```

**db_config.env**

```
MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root
MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=example

ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=root
ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=example

ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=mongo
ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_PORT=27017
```

I also have these messages with the mongo-express container :

```
(node:8) [MONGODB DRIVER] Warning: Current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.

basicAuth credentials are "admin:pass", it is recommended you change this in your config.js!

(node:8) [MONGODB DRIVER] Warning: Current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.

Could not connect to database using connectionString: mongodb://root:example@mongo:27017/"

(node:8) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [mongo:27017] on first connect [Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN mongo

at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:66:26) {

name: 'MongoNetworkError'

}]

at Pool.<anonymous> (/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/topologies/server.js:441:11)

at Pool.emit (events.js:314:20)

at /node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:564:14

at /node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:999:11

at /node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:32:7

at callback (/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:283:5)

at Socket.<anonymous> (/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:313:7)

at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:421:26)

at Socket.emit (events.js:314:20)

at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)

at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)

at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)

(node:8) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)

(node:8) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

(node:8) [MONGODB DRIVER] Warning: Current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.

Could not connect to database using connectionString: mongodb://root:example@mongo:27017/"

(node:8) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [mongo:27017] on first connect [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.18.0.5:27017

at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1144:16) {

name: 'MongoNetworkError'

}]

at Pool.<anonymous> (/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/topologies/server.js:441:11)

at Pool.emit (events.js:314:20)

at /node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:564:14

at /node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:999:11

at /node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:32:7

at callback (/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:283:5)

at Socket.<anonymous> (/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:313:7)

at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:421:26)

at Socket.emit (events.js:314:20)

at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)

at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)

at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)

(node:8) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)

(node:8) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

(node:8) [MONGODB DRIVER] Warning: Current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.
```

Thank you a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I got this error and in my case it was a version mismatch for mongoimport. The system I was installing on had the Ubuntu (21) distribution apt version installed that had 'built-without-version-string' (wtf? my words)  for mongoimport --version. I installed the latest version which was 100.5.0 and the error went away.

So even if you are not using mongoimport, this error could probably occur with other mongo utils and such if the versions don't match up.